# Convert a integer to a part of a string constant

Tags: c, string, integer

How can I convert an integer(input) to a part of a string & output the whole string ??
e.g - suppose input is an year & output is Date.In Date format(dd-mm-yyyy) date & month part is same,only year is variable which we'll get by input.
suppose year is 2007(input)
then our output will be 12.09.2007.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    char name[15];
    int year;
    scanf("%d", &year);
    int len = sprintf(name, "12.09.%04d", year);
    if(len < 0 || (unsigned)len >= sizeof name)//checking success of sprintf
    {
        printf("error in name");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor: 1) it would make more sense to return non-0 or `EXIT_FAILURE` in error block and 2) use `snprintf()`.  `(unsigned)len >= sizeof name` is only true  after  UB.

Comment: @hanie Can't understand the logic behind if() part. Can u please explain ??

Comment: @Mrinmoy `sprintf` will return number of bytes ,it writes in `name` and if it failed those condition will happen , this is to check if it didn't fail to write what you want in `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * format = "DD.MM.%d";
int year = 2020;
scanf("%d", &year);
printf(format, year);
```